Find intersection between two Revit elements in APS (forge) viewer
I'm using APS (forge) viewer version 7.* to view Revit models.
Is it possible to find out if two elements (e.g. a pipe and a duct) are intersecting each other by viewer rayIntersect method? If so, can you hint me how implement it?

Looking around there seem to be multiple options depending on how accurate this needs to be. 
From least accurate to most accurate:

check the bounding box of each object and intersect them
create rays based on the first object (e.g. between its vertices) and intersect them with the other object's mesh: 
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/03/threejs-raytracing-in-the-forge-viewer.html 
https://www.keanw.com/2022/03/detecting-collisions-in-the-forge-viewer.html
create BSP meshes for both objects and do boolean operations between them: 
https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/boolean-operations-forge-viewer

